# Image doesn't fit in container when using <img> but does with background-image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have an image be the background of a div/container in its full size regardless of how much content there is in the div itself.

When I try:

```
<div class = 'container-fluid'>
   <img src="image.jpeg" style="object-fit: cover;" />
</div>
```

The image has the full height but the image stretches further than the width of the screen (since the resolution is quite high).
However when I add the image as a background it seems to be fine, squishing the width to match the page but allowing the full height, but since the size of the background is defined by the contents inside I tried:

```
<div class = 'container-fluid' style="background-image: url(image.jpeg);">
 <img src="image.jpg" style="visibility: hidden; object-fit:cover;" />
</div>
```

While this does give the intended result (which is also confusing since object-fit should behave like background-size) it adds a horizontal scroll bar with a blank area to the right of the image, since I guess while it is hidden it is still on the page.
How would I be able to get rid of that extra white space from the page, or is there a better way to go about just having the image squished to match the screen width but have full height regardless of the content of the div?
Thanks so much in advance

Comment: I didn't include it in the code but I have a bootstrap CDN in my head

Comment: *I have a bootstrap CDN in my head* I'd prefer if that was in your code. A CDN in your head could cause health issues :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve with this but I will try to explain the things you mentioned.

In your first example, the image is unconstrained (no specified width or height), so it takes up its original size, which ever resoultion the image has. The container just wraps around it, it doesn't contain it. But when you add the image as a background-image, it is just the background of the container so it has the same size as the container.

In the second example, you again have the same image, which takes up its original size (wider than your screen), but while it is hidden, it is still there. MDN documentation on [visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) states that `visibility` shows or hides an element **without changing the layout**. That is why you get the scroll bar with a blank area, as the image is still part of the layout.

`object-fit` is like `background-size`, but what probably confuses you is that you probably think that `object-fit` will resize the image based on the size of the container. While in reality it works based on the size of the image itself. For example, if you set the image width and height to 200px (or some value smaller than the image resolution), then `object-fit` will work as you expect it to.

And for the solution, as I said I don't exactly know what you want to achieve, but I think this might help.

An obvious solution is to just set the container to the size you want and set the image as the background. Using this you can also use `background-position` property.

To use the `img` tag, you can take your first example, and add `position: relative;` to the container element and set `width: 100%; height: 100%` to the image element.

And if you want the image to be the width of the sceen, you can use any of these two methods and set either the size of the container or the image size to `width: 100vw; height: 100vh;`. `vw` and `vh` is viewport width and height. You can read more about it on MDN documentation on [CSS length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length).

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write such a detailed response. Pretty much what I was looking for was solved using the vw and vh values, thanks again :)